# Como ordenar y filtrar arreglo de forma decreciente según información de otro arreglo?

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs, algoritmos

Tengo 3 arreglos, uno de ventas, uno de vendedores y otro de productos, cada uno con información necesaria. El de ventas contiene los id de los productos y de sus vendedores

```
const vendedores = [
  { id: 1, name: "Juan" },
  { id: 2, name: "Carlos" },
  { id: 3, name: "Fede" },
  { id: 4, name: "Matias" },
];

const productos = [
  { id: 1, credencial: "132254524", name: "televisores" },
  { id: 2, credencial: "143618668", name: "estufas" },
  { id: 3, credencial: "78903228", name: "celulares" },
  { id: 4, credencial: "176812737", name: "Audio" },
  { id: 5, credencial: "216352696", name: "heladeras" },
];

//arreglo de objetos que contiene el id del producto vendido, el id de su vendedor y la cantidad
const ventas = [
  { productosId: 2, vendedorId: 1, cantidad: 1200 },
  { productosId: 1, vendedorId: 1, cantidad: 500 },
  { productosId: 5, vendedorId: 2, cantidad: 20000 },
  { productosId: 2, vendedorId: 3, cantidad: 8401 },
  { productosId: 3, vendedorId: 1, cantidad: 2877 },
  { productosId: 3, vendedorId: 2, cantidad: 1736 },
  { productosId: 2, vendedorId: 3, cantidad: 2965 },
  { productosId: 4, vendedorId: 4, cantidad: 1651 },
  { productosId: 5, vendedorId: 1, cantidad: 700 },
  { productosId: 1, vendedorId: 1, cantidad: 7956 },
];
```

En base a esto se me pide un arreglo ordenado de mayor a menor con la suma de las ventas de juan por producto, es decir con la cantidad total de cada producto vendido. El objetivo deberia verse asi:

```
//cada elemento del array corresponde a la suma de ventas de un producto especifico por juan
const resultado=  [8456, 2877, 1200, 700, 0]
```

Pude realizar la tarea, pero lo realice de una forma poco optimizada y nada escalable. Se que hay mejores formas de realizarlo, mas optimizada y automatizada; estoy abierto a respuestas.

Así fue como lo intente hacer:

```
//Utilizo un filter y un reduce para filtrar y sumar cada cantidad vendida por producto lo que hace a mi funcion poco optimizada

function arregloVentasJuan() {
  
  const arreglo = [];
  const ventasJuan = ventas.filter((e) => e.vendedorId === 1);

  const ventaProducto1 = ventasJuan
    .filter((e) => e.productosId === 1)
    .reduce((acc, e) => acc + e.cantidad, 0);
  arreglo.push(ventaProducto1);

  const ventaProducto2 = ventasJuan
    .filter((e) => e.productosId === 2)
    .reduce((acc, e) => acc + e.cantidad, 0);
  arreglo.push(ventaProducto2);

  const ventaProducto3 = ventasJuan
    .filter((e) => e.productosId === 3)
    .reduce((acc, e) => acc + e.cantidad, 0);
  arreglo.push(ventaProducto3);

  const ventaProducto4 = ventasJuan
    .filter((e) => e.productosId === 4)
    .reduce((acc, e) => acc + e.cantidad, 0);
  arreglo.push(ventaProducto4);

  const ventaProducto5 = ventasJuan
    .filter((e) => e.productosId === 5)
    .reduce((acc, e) => acc + e.cantidad, 0);
  arreglo.push(ventaProducto5);

  return arreglo.sort((a, b) => b - a);
}
```

Comment: En el arreglo de resultado, además de saber la cantidad, ¿no te estaría faltando saber que productos son?

Comment: No, solo requiero sumar las cantidades de los productos y ordenarlo en un arreglo

Answer (score 1):

Podrías obtener el resultado recorriendo:

- El arreglo de ventas, para obtener los totales.
- El arreglo de totales, para ordenarlo.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function arregloVentas(id) {
  let hash = {}; // <- Lo usamos para guardar {productId: posicion}
  return ventas.reduce((acc, {vendedorId, productosId, cantidad}) => {
      if (hash[productosId] === undefined) { // <- Si el producto no esta en el hash
        hash[productosId] = acc.length; // <- guardamos la posicion en el arreglo
        acc.push(0); // <- inicializamos en cero
      }
      if (vendedorId !== id) return acc; // <- Si es de otro vendor
      acc[hash[productosId]] += cantidad // <- sumamos la cantidad vendida
      return acc;
    }, [])
    .sort((a, b) => b - a);
}

const ventas = [
  { productosId: 2, vendedorId: 1, cantidad: 1200 },
  { productosId: 1, vendedorId: 1, cantidad: 500 },
  { productosId: 5, vendedorId: 2, cantidad: 20000 },
  { productosId: 2, vendedorId: 3, cantidad: 8401 },
  { productosId: 3, vendedorId: 1, cantidad: 2877 },
  { productosId: 3, vendedorId: 2, cantidad: 1736 },
  { productosId: 2, vendedorId: 3, cantidad: 2965 },
  { productosId: 4, vendedorId: 4, cantidad: 1651 },
  { productosId: 5, vendedorId: 1, cantidad: 700 },
  { productosId: 1, vendedorId: 1, cantidad: 7956 },
];
const ventasDeJuan = arregloVentas(1);
console.log(ventasDeJuan)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function arregloVentasJuan (){
for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
let ventasJuan=ventas.filter((e) => e.vendedorId ===1).filter((e) => e.productosId === i)
    .reduce((acc, e) => acc + e.cantidad, 0);
arreglo.push(ventasJuan);   
}
return arreglo.sort((a, b) => b - a));
}


console.log(arregloVentasJuan())
//[ 8456, 2877, 1200, 700, 0 ]
```

Con parametro

```
function ventasVendedor (ID){
for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
let ventasJuan=ventas.filter((e) => e.vendedorId ===ID
).filter((e) => e.productosId === i)
    .reduce((acc, e) => acc + e.cantidad, 0);
arreglo.push(ventasJuan);   
}
return arreglo.sort((a, b) => b - a);
}


console.log(ventasVendedor(2))
//[ 20000, 1736, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haria de este modo para conseguir no solo lo de Juan, sino ya todos, e independientemente de si luego hay más productos o menos:

```
function arregloVentas(id) {

  const arreglo = [];
  const ventasById = ventas.filter((e) => e.vendedorId === id);

  productos.forEach(element => {
    const ventaProducto = ventasById
      .filter((e) => e.productosId === element.id)
      .reduce((acc, e) => acc + e.cantidad, 0);
    arreglo.push(ventaProducto);
  });

  return arreglo.sort((a, b) => b - a);
}

vendedores.forEach(vendedor => {
  console.log(vendedor.name + "=" + arregloVentas(vendedor.id))
  console.log(arregloVentas(vendedor.id))
})
```

Y si solo quieres lo de Juan entonces seria cambiar lo del final por:

```
console.log(arregloVentas(1))
```

Snippet de muestra:

```js
const vendedores = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Juan"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Carlos"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Fede"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Matias"
  },
];

const productos = [{
    id: 1,
    credencial: "132254524",
    name: "televisores"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    credencial: "143618668",
    name: "estufas"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    credencial: "78903228",
    name: "celulares"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    credencial: "176812737",
    name: "Audio"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    credencial: "216352696",
    name: "heladeras"
  },
];

//arreglo de objetos que contiene el id del producto vendido, el id de su vendedor y la cantidad
const ventas = [{
    productosId: 2,
    vendedorId: 1,
    cantidad: 1200
  },
  {
    productosId: 1,
    vendedorId: 1,
    cantidad: 500
  },
  {
    productosId: 5,
    vendedorId: 2,
    cantidad: 20000
  },
  {
    productosId: 2,
    vendedorId: 3,
    cantidad: 8401
  },
  {
    productosId: 3,
    vendedorId: 1,
    cantidad: 2877
  },
  {
    productosId: 3,
    vendedorId: 2,
    cantidad: 1736
  },
  {
    productosId: 2,
    vendedorId: 3,
    cantidad: 2965
  },
  {
    productosId: 4,
    vendedorId: 4,
    cantidad: 1651
  },
  {
    productosId: 5,
    vendedorId: 1,
    cantidad: 700
  },
  {
    productosId: 1,
    vendedorId: 1,
    cantidad: 7956
  },
];

//Utilizo un filter y un reduce para filtrar y sumar cada cantidad vendida por producto lo que hace a mi funcion poco optimizada

function arregloVentas(id) {

  const arreglo = [];
  const ventasById = ventas.filter((e) => e.vendedorId === id);

  productos.forEach(element => {
    const ventaProducto = ventasById
      .filter((e) => e.productosId === element.id)
      .reduce((acc, e) => acc + e.cantidad, 0);
    arreglo.push(ventaProducto);
  });

  return arreglo.sort((a, b) => b - a);
}

vendedores.forEach(vendedor => {
  console.log(vendedor.name + "=" + arregloVentas(vendedor.id))
  console.log(arregloVentas(vendedor.id))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes solucionar así

```js
const vendedores = [
  { id: 1, name: "Juan" },
  { id: 2, name: "Carlos" },
  { id: 3, name: "Fede" },
  { id: 4, name: "Matias" },
];

const productos = [
  { id: 1, credencial: "132254524", name: "televisores" },
  { id: 2, credencial: "143618668", name: "estufas" },
  { id: 3, credencial: "78903228", name: "celulares" },
  { id: 4, credencial: "176812737", name: "Audio" },
  { id: 5, credencial: "216352696", name: "heladeras" },
];

//arreglo de objetos que contiene el id del producto vendido, el id de su vendedor y la cantidad
const ventas = [
  { productosId: 2, vendedorId: 1, cantidad: 1200 },
  { productosId: 1, vendedorId: 1, cantidad: 500 },
  { productosId: 5, vendedorId: 2, cantidad: 20000 },
  { productosId: 2, vendedorId: 3, cantidad: 8401 },
  { productosId: 3, vendedorId: 1, cantidad: 2877 },
  { productosId: 3, vendedorId: 2, cantidad: 1736 },
  { productosId: 2, vendedorId: 3, cantidad: 2965 },
  { productosId: 4, vendedorId: 4, cantidad: 1651 },
  { productosId: 5, vendedorId: 1, cantidad: 700 },
  { productosId: 1, vendedorId: 1, cantidad: 7956 },
];

let result = Object.values(ventas.reduce((acc, {vendedorId, productosId, cantidad}) => {
  if(vendedorId === 1){
    acc[`prod${productosId}`] = acc[`prod${productosId}`] || 0; //Lo creo si no existe
    acc[`prod${productosId}`] += cantidad;
  }
  return acc;
}, {})).sort((a,b) => b-a);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Pipe me ayudo mucho tu respuesta, no me vendría mal una mano en unos ejercicios similares a este. Hay alguna forma de contactarte para que me aconsejes, no se demorara mucho (obviamente te pagare)